Apache Solr 9+ - Full and partial text match on single field
I am trying to find a way to configure my Apache Sorl 9+ schema to have the option to search in the text field either - full-text match or partial word match.
For example, if I have the field address that contains Westminster, London SW1A 0AA, UK

Full text match. I want by default only when there is an exact full address match of this doc to be returned - new SolrQuery("address:Westminster, London SW1A 0AA, UK")
Partial text match. I want also to have the option to search partially using the * approach - new SolrQuery("address:*SW1A 0AA*")

I went over many articles but could not find a way for this configuration, so any help will be highly appreciated

That should work with the default string field (which is case sensitive), or by using a KeywordTokenizer with a lowercase field (to make it case insensitive). Be aware that prefix wildcards can be rather expensive, as it means that every token needs to be searched. If you're always using it as a postcode, it's better to not use a wildcard and have a separate field which tokenizes on spaces (or extract the postcode to a separate field and search against that). Different behaviors will usually require multiple fields, configured with copyField to index the same content into more fields.

@MatsLindh thanks for the response. First I tried with standard <tokenizer name="standard"/> but couldn't find a way to search based on a full-text match. Later I tried <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/> where I had the ability using "address:\"London SW1A 0AAA, UK\"" to do full-text search but partial did not work properly, so I am wondering can I have a single field for both purposes or I need from two with dedicated behavior using proper Analyzer and Tokenizers? If we can, please share some examples. Thanks!

You'll want to have two fields with separate behaviors if you want to have different query profiles, or you could use the complex query parser together with with a whitespace tokenizer or standard tokenizer (with inOrder set). This might be expensive over a large dataset however; the more processing you can move to the indexing stage, the better. Examples depends on what you need examples for, but searching for copyFields in the reference manual and here on SO should give you a decent start. The query profile will depend on the field definitions.
